# How do you add an Event Listener that fires when tinymce get function gets called?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

This [tinymce get function](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.get.static) returns an Editor instance when passed an id. I would like to have an event fire (or a callback) every time this function is called:

```
tinymce.get('mytextbox')
```

I have tried:

```
tinymce.on('Get', function(e){console.log('Get called!',e);});
```

But that didn't work. Is there anything built into tinymce for this?

Comment: I don't think such a functionality exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, there is no such functionality built in Tinymce.